# AzureCloud Service Deployment TeamCity

Tags: azure, deployment, powershell-2.0, azure-cloud-services

I am having a difficult time deploying to azure cloud services using my CI platform Teamcity. THe script runs fine when I run it through Powershell ISE, but as soon as I point TC at the ps1 file to run, I get a ton or errors that my Current storage account is not set.

```
Azure Cloud Service deploy script started.
Preparing deployment of ContinuousDeploy to myapp for Free Trial Free Trial         with Subscription ID  deployidstring.
No deployment is detected. Creating a new deployment. 
Creating New Deployment: In progress
New-AzureDeployment : CurrentStorageAccountName is not set. Use 
Set-AzureSubscription subname -Current StorageAccountName storageaccount to set it.
```

Here is the code that I am using "pretty much the same as MS default script"

```
Param(  $serviceName = "myapp",
        $storageAccountName = "stoageaccountdevqa",
        $packageLocation = "E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\buildid\src\myapp\bin\Release\app.publish\myapp.cspkg",
        $cloudConfigLocation = "E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\buildid\src\myapp\bin\Release\app.publish\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg",
        $environment = "Staging",
        $deploymentLabel = "ContinuousDeploy to $servicename",
        $timeStampFormat = "g",
        $alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments = 1,
        $enableDeploymentUpgrade = 1,
        $selectedsubscription = "Free Trial",
        $subscriptionDataFile = "E:\TeamCity\pubsettings.publishsettings"
     )

Write-Output "Running Azure Imports"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\AzurePreview.psd1"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\AzureProfile.psd1"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\ExpressRoute.psd1"
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "E:\TeamCity\pubsettings.publishsettings"
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SubscriptionName $selectedsubscription
function Publish()
{
    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot -ErrorVariable a -ErrorAction silentlycontinue 
    if ($a[0] -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - No deployment is detected. Creating a new deployment. "
    }
    #check for existing deployment and then either upgrade, delete + deploy, or cancel according to $alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments and $enableDeploymentUpgrade boolean     variables
    if ($deployment.Name -ne $null)
    {
        switch ($alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments)
        {
            1 
            {
                switch ($enableDeploymentUpgrade)
                {
                    1  #Update deployment inplace (usually faster, cheaper, won't destroy VIP)
                    {
                        Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Deployment exists in $servicename.  Upgrading deployment."
                        UpgradeDeployment
                    }
                    0  #Delete then create new deployment
                    {
                        Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Deployment exists in $servicename.  Deleting deployment."
                        DeleteDeployment
                        CreateNewDeployment

                    }
                } # switch ($enableDeploymentUpgrade)
            }
            0
            {
                Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - ERROR: Deployment exists in $servicename.  Script execution cancelled."
                exit
            }
        } #switch ($alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments)
    } else {
            CreateNewDeployment
    }
}

function CreateNewDeployment()
{
    write-progress -id 3 -activity "Creating New Deployment" -Status "In progress"
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Creating New Deployment: In progress"


    $opstat = New-AzureDeployment -Slot $slot -Package $packageLocation -Configuration $cloudConfigLocation -label $deploymentLabel -ServiceName $serviceName

    $completeDeployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
    $completeDeploymentID = $completeDeployment.deploymentid

    write-progress -id 3 -activity "Creating New Deployment" -completed -Status "Complete"
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Creating New Deployment: Complete, Deployment ID: $completeDeploymentID"

    StartInstances
}

function UpgradeDeployment()
{
    write-progress -id 3 -activity "Upgrading Deployment" -Status "In progress"
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Upgrading Deployment: In progress"


    Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SubscriptionName $selectedsubscription
    # perform Update-Deployment
    $setdeployment = Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package $packageLocation -Configuration $cloudConfigLocation -label $deploymentLabel -ServiceName     $serviceName -Force

    $completeDeployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
    $completeDeploymentID = $completeDeployment.deploymentid

    write-progress -id 3 -activity "Upgrading Deployment" -completed -Status "Complete"
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Upgrading Deployment: Complete, Deployment ID: $completeDeploymentID"
}

function DeleteDeployment()
{

    write-progress -id 2 -activity "Deleting Deployment" -Status "In progress"
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Deleting Deployment: In progress"

    #WARNING - always deletes with force
    $removeDeployment = Remove-AzureDeployment -Slot $slot -ServiceName $serviceName -Force

    write-progress -id 2 -activity "Deleting Deployment: Complete" -completed -Status $removeDeployment
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Deleting Deployment: Complete"

}

function StartInstances()
{
    write-progress -id 4 -activity "Starting Instances" -status "In progress"
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instances: In progress"

    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
    $runstatus = $deployment.Status

    if ($runstatus -ne 'Running') 
    {
        $run = Set-AzureDeployment -Slot $slot -ServiceName $serviceName -Status Running
    }
    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
    $oldStatusStr = @("") * $deployment.RoleInstanceList.Count

    while (-not(AllInstancesRunning($deployment.RoleInstanceList)))
    {
        $i = 1
        foreach ($roleInstance in $deployment.RoleInstanceList)
        {
            $instanceName = $roleInstance.InstanceName
            $instanceStatus = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus

            if ($oldStatusStr[$i - 1] -ne $roleInstance.InstanceStatus)
            {
                $oldStatusStr[$i - 1] = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus
                Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instance '$instanceName': $instanceStatus"
            }

            write-progress -id (4 + $i) -activity "Starting Instance '$instanceName'" -status "$instanceStatus"
            $i = $i + 1
        }

        sleep -Seconds 1

        $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
    }

    $i = 1
    foreach ($roleInstance in $deployment.RoleInstanceList)
    {
        $instanceName = $roleInstance.InstanceName
        $instanceStatus = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus

        if ($oldStatusStr[$i - 1] -ne $roleInstance.InstanceStatus)
        {
            $oldStatusStr[$i - 1] = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instance '$instanceName': $instanceStatus"
        }

        $i = $i + 1
    }

    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
    $opstat = $deployment.Status 

    write-progress -id 4 -activity "Starting Instances" -completed -status $opstat
    Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instances: $opstat"
}

function AllInstancesRunning($roleInstanceList)
{
    foreach ($roleInstance in $roleInstanceList)
    {
        if ($roleInstance.InstanceStatus -ne "ReadyRole")
        {
            return $false
        }
    }

    return $true
}

#configure powershell with Azure 1.7 modules
#Import-Module Azure

#configure powershell with publishsettings for your subscription
$pubsettings = $subscriptionDataFile
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $pubsettings
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SubscriptionName $selectedsubscription

#set remaining environment variables for Azure cmdlets
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription $selectedsubscription
$subscriptionname = $subscription.subscriptionname
$subscriptionid = $subscription.subscriptionid
$slot = $environment

#main driver - publish & write progress to activity log
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Azure Cloud Service deploy script started."
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Preparing deployment of $deploymentLabel for $subscriptionname with Subscription ID $subscriptionid."

Publish

$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -slot $slot -serviceName $servicename
$deploymentUrl = $deployment.Url

Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Created Cloud Service with URL $deploymentUrl."
Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Azure Cloud Service deploy script finished."
```

I have tried a few things like reimporting the files and then explicitly setting the currentstorage account before running the script or in both the update and new deploy sections before any work is done. Neither of these helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you you cannot include the subscription name as a named parameter

Try this once

```
Set-AzureSubscription $subscription -CurrentStorageAccount $service
```

instead of

```
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SubscriptionName $selectedsubscription
```